# Unity2D: How to check for overlap using the job system

Tags: unity, c#

Currently, I have implemented a job in unity for performance reasons. In that job, I am checking if a game object overlaps with the "detection circle". The job looks like this:

```
[BurstCompile]
public struct CreateGridJob : IJob
{
    public float diameter, radius;
    public NativeArray<int2> positionsArray;
    public NativeArray<bool> isWallArray;
    public float3 bottomLeft;
    public int sizeX, sizeY;
    public float3 right, up;
    public LayerMask layer;

    public void Execute()
    {
        int x = 0, y = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < positionsArray.Length; i++)
        {
            float3 point = bottomLeft + right * (x * diameter + radius) + up * (y * diameter + radius);
            bool wall = true;
            Vector3 worldPoint = point;
            if (Physics2D.OverlapCircle(worldPoint, radius, layer))
                wall = false;
            positionsArray[i] = new int2(x, y);
            isWallArray[i] = wall;


            if (x % sizeX == 0)
                x++;

            y++;
            if (y >= sizeY)
                y = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem course when I have to call `if (Physics2D.OverlapCircle(worldPoint, radius, layer))`as it can only be called in the main thread thus throwing an exception.

The result of this job will be a grid to be used in pathfinding.

Am I going in the right direction or is there a different way of doing this?

Edit-1: Unfortunately no, not all are convex (can be changed if there's no other way).

Here is an example of a concave asteroid:

[image]

There are many of these asteroids scattered across the scene. First, they are grouped in sectors, and each sector has its own asteroids. Sectors are independent of each other and are only connected through portals. For the simulation purposes, all (at least for now) sectors are active and generate their grid. But a single sector can have for example 200 asteroids. They are placed at random.

Edit-2: Flow!
A script generates sectors and their children.
In this script on Update, I call the CreateGridJobHandle. which gets the Job handles and then I execute them.

```
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Helper.IsStatusGraterOrEqual(GameStatus.FirstSectorGridSet))
        {
            NativeArray<JobHandle> jobHandleList = new NativeArray<JobHandle>(Sectors.Count, Allocator.TempJob);
            for (int i = 0; i < Sectors.Count; i++)
            {
                JobHandle handle = Sectors[i].SectorGrid.CreateGridJobHandle();
                jobHandleList[i] = handle;
            }
            JobHandle.CompleteAll(jobHandleList);
            jobHandleList.Dispose();


            for (int i = 0; i < Sectors.Count; i++)
            {
                Sectors[i].SectorGrid.SetGridFromData();
            }
        }
    }
```

```
    public JobHandle CreateGridJobHandle()
    {
        CreateGridJob job = new CreateGridJob();
        jobPositionsArray = new NativeArray<int2>(gridSizeX * gridSizeY, Allocator.TempJob);
        jobWallsArray = new NativeArray<bool>(gridSizeX * gridSizeY, Allocator.TempJob);

        job.positionsArray = jobPositionsArray;
        job.isWallArray = jobWallsArray;
        job.diameter = nodeDiameter;
        job.bottomLeft = transform.position - Vector3.right * GridWorldSize.x * 0.5f - Vector3.up * GridWorldSize.y * 0.5f;
        job.sizeX = gridSizeX;
        job.sizeY = gridSizeY;
        job.right = Vector3.right;
        job.up = Vector3.up;
        job.radius = NodeRadius;
        job.layer = WallMask;

        return job.Schedule();
    }
```

After this, I just set the grid into 2d array and apply the isWall values.

````
    public void SetGridFromData()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < jobPositionsArray.Length; i++)
        {
            if (jobWallsArray[i])
            {
                grid[jobPositionsArray[i].x, jobPositionsArray[i].y].IsWall = jobWallsArray[i];
            }

        }
        jobWallsArray.Dispose();
        jobPositionsArray.Dispose();
    }
```
````

Comment: What specific colliders are you hoping to detect with OverlapCircle? Do they have any commonality, patterns or structure we can use to do our own threadsafe check without replicating the full complexity of the general-purpose physics engine itself?

Comment: Thank you for your response @DMGregory. Currently, I'm trying to detect Polygon Collider 2D

Comment: That's not much to go on yet. Can you show us a screenshot or diagram of a typical case? What kinds of polygon shapes do you need to detect? Can we guarantee they're convex? How many of them are there in your scene? Is there any pattern to their placement or spacing? etc...

Comment: If I can provide any more info, just ask :)

Comment: @DMGregory is Physics2D.OverlapCircle even the right choice for this job, I read somewhere that using Ray would work

Comment: It's hard for us to know what job you're doing here, to advise whether radius checks, rays, or another tool might be more appropriate. Want to edit your question to tell us more about the context of how this code gets used in your game?

Comment: @DMGregory Sure, hope this helps